# How to replicate an image based on an integer value on ItextSharp

Tags: vb.net, itext

I am trying to make copies of a Logo according to how many times the user has inputted. But I can only make one copy of the image cause I don't know how to replicate it based on an integer value.

Here is my code:

```
Public Function print_logo()
Dim image as image // I cut off the file path cause I don't need that as an explanation
img.ScalePercent(40.0F) // COMPANY LOGO
img.Alignment = iTextSharp.text.Image.ALIGN_CENTER

'Exporting to PDF

Dim folderPath As String = "C:\Temp\"
If Not Directory.Exists(folderPath) Then
    Directory.CreateDirectory(folderPath)
End If

Using stream As New FileStream(folderPath & "temp2.pdf", FileMode.Create)
    Dim pgsize As New iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(216, 504)
    Dim pdfdoc As New Document(pgsize, 15.0F, 15.0F, 10.0F, 20.0F)
    PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, stream)

    pdfDoc.Open()
    pdfDoc.Add(img)
    pdfDoc.Close()
    stream.Close()


    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("C:\\Temp\\temp2.pdf")

End Using


Return True
End Function
```

Comment: If you want to do something repeatedly then you use a loop. There are a very limited number of types of loops so I will let you work out which is the best to use in this case. Loops are one of the fundamentals of programming in any language so the fact that you didn't even know to use one here indicates that you should not be writing any code at all before learning the fundamentals properly. I suggest [this tutorial](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/NET/vbNet.html).

Comment: I know loops very well, it’s just I don’t know how to loop this one and export it in a single document

Comment: @jmcilhinney can you modify my code and put a for loop in it? I just don’t know where to cut the code in order for the loop to run and export a single document

Comment: We're not here to write your code for you. If you know loops very well then use some logic to make the best attempt you can and show us that. If you haven't tried then you haven't failed and if you haven't failed then posting a question here is premature.